# How to find only my AWS ECS Task in multiple running copies of the same task?

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, command-line-interface, task, amazon-ecs

I'm running a bash script inside docker image. Script is using AWS S3 commands to copy files from S3 bucket and passes it to the SQL Loader to load data to an Oracle database. Upon completion file on S3 either deleted if load OK, or moved to S3/bad directory if load failed.
AWS trigger fires an ECS cluster task upon arrival of a file into S3 bucket. Task starts a docker container. If several files arrived at the same time then multiple parallel tasks will be triggered.

Is it possible in a bash script to use AWS CLI commands or any other mechanism to get something unique from a parent task? Task ARN or something else unique in this bunch of tasks and relates only to this copy of a docker container?

I need it to be able to mark a processing file, so no other tasks would go after it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Task ARN from within the container running in ECS via the ECS Metadata API. The API is slightly different depending on if your tasks are running on [EC2 instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint-v4.html) or [Fargate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint-v4-fargate.html), but in either case you would hit the `${ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI_V4}/task` Metadata API endpoint, and parse out the Task ARN from the JSON response that comes back.